# Uniform convergence of $f_n=\sqrt[n]{x}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, uniform-convergence

Check the pointwise and uniform convergence of
$$f_n:[0,\infty[\to\mathbb{R}, x\mapsto\sqrt[n]{x}$$

i assume that $f_n \to f$ is pointwise convergent  with $f:[0,\infty[\to \mathbb{R},f(x):=
\begin{cases} 
1  &, x\gt 0 \\[2ex]
0 &, x=0
\end{cases}$

since for all $\lim_{n->\infty} \sqrt[n]{x}\to 1, \forall x\gt0 $ and $\lim_{n->\infty} \sqrt[n]{x}\to0 $ for $x=0$

My question is, is it sufficient enough that the $f$ it approaches is not continuous to say that $f_n$ is not uniform continuous?

Comment: No. You also have to mention that each $f_n$ is continuous.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thank you. What i'm wondering though is that if instead $f_n$ was defined as $]0,\infty[$ i would get why i would then have to show that the series of functions is actually approach uniformly. what i was wondering is the fact that $f$ is not continous and therefore $f_n$ shouldn't be, right?

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos i've found a Lemma that says $f_n\to f$ uniformly $\implies f$ is continous. With the contraposition i have what i was looking for and i don't have to show it for each $f_n$

Comment: There is no such lemma. Take **any** discontinuous function $f$ and define $f_n=f$. Then $(f_m)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges uniformly to $f$, but $f$ is still discontinuous.

Comment: i have to correct myself. The Lemma says  if all $f_n$ are continous and $f_n \to f$ uniformly $\implies f$ is continous

Comment: And therefore, the fact the $f$ is discontinuous is not enough to prove that the convergence is not uniform. It must also be checked that each $f_n$ is continuous.